# Do monsters get a second wind?

Tags: dnd-4e, second-wind

In the early adventure, Siege of Borodin's Watch I found this curious statement:

> If the militants are bloodied, they shift back
>   and spend their second wind, jumping back into the
>   thick of battle at the start of their next
>   turn.

Do monsters get a second wind? Have they ever?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Monsters do not normally get a Second Wind**.

From [Second Wind](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=334):

> Unless otherwise noted in the statistics block of a monster or a nonplayer character, this action is available only to player characters.

However they do have Healing Surges, they just lack an easy way to use them during combat.

From [Healing Surge](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=160):

> Monsters and NPCs: As a general rule, monsters and nonplayer characters have a number of healing surges based on their tier:
>
> - one healing surge at the heroic tier (1st–10th levels)
> - two healing surges at the paragon tier (11th–20th levels)
> - three healing surges at the epic tier (21st–30th levels).

Comment: That's what I thought. Nice quoting :)

Answer (score 8):

4E monsters, by default, have healing surges depending on their tier, but no way to access them in combat (unless they have a friendly Leader heal them, or use a potion of healing).

But specific beats general, and if the monster's description says it has a second wind, it does.